# javascript global array

Tags: javascript

I am having below html code and trying to add new values to global array by onchanging of javascript function.I am trying to do  like below way.But it is giving javascript errors.Please suggest anyone how to do this.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
var list=[];
function getList(value){

list=list(value);
}
</script>

</head>

<body>

<tr>
<td>
<select name="test" onchange="getList(this)">
<option id="1" value="one">One</option>
<option id="2" value="two">two</option>

</select>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<select name="test1" onchange="getList(this)">
<option id="3" value="three">three</option>
<option id="4" value="four">four</option>

</select>
</td>
</tr>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How about telling us what the error is? Is the function `list` defined somewhere (I guess not)? I suggest you read a JavaScript tutorial first: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change your `Javascript` to the following

```
var list=new Array; ///this one way of declaring array in javascript
function getList(value){

list.push(value);//push function will insert values in the list array
}
```

Comment: Thanks,Is values are adding to next index or same index?

Comment: No need to change `[]` to `new Array`

Comment: @user569125: `list.push()` will add the values to next index

Answer (score 0):

Adding values to an array is quite simple, all you have to do is call the `push(..)` method.

Like so:

```
var list = [ ];
list.push(1);

console.info(list); // Outputs: [ 1 ]
```

- [Mozilla array reference](http://www.google.nl/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBgQFjAA&url=https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array&ei=s9iiTZO6LIeBOpnZtDQ&usg=AFQjCNGDI18N3No8YyJy-R9tak3YbAi_bA)
- [Mozilla array push reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)

Answer (score 0):

You're currently passing the entire select element to your function, rather than the selected value.  You can pass the selected value like this:

```
getList(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)
```

Then you can use `list.push(value)` in your function to add the selected value to your array.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to add a value to an array in JavaScript, it to use the `push` method (unless you need to support IE5):

```
function getList(value) {
  list.push(value);
}
```

Two things:

- In your case this would add references to the select elements to the list. That's most likely not what you want. What exactly do you want to add?
- `getList` isn't really a suitable name for that. `addToList` would be probably better.